# Move child theme style.css without plugin

Tags: wordpress, render-blocking

I am optimizing performance of my WordPress website
The style.css of my child theme is coming under render blocking resources I need to move it from header to footer
Code inside Child theme's function.php is

```
function softek_child_enqueue_styles() {    
    wp_enqueue_style( 'softek-child-style',
        get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/style.css',
        array( 'softek-style' ),
        1.0
    );
}
add_action(  'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'softek_child_enqueue_styles', 99 );
```

I have commented this code but the file is still loading